# Magento2: Order Number increment issue

Tags: magento2, sequence, order-increment

I have got a issue with Order Number in Magento2.
[image]

Order Number not increment by 1
it should be like this
000000241
000000240
000000239
but not.kindly identify the issue.

Comment: Can you please check try to sort by ID instead of purchase Date.

Comment: i have set sort by ID but same result . orders id increment by 3 , can you identify why increment by 3?

Comment: have you solve this issue i am also facing this  issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many reasons why an order number (increment id) is missing in your list. One common case is that an order number is created before the order will be saved. That happens for example in some payment modules. If the customer doesn't finish the checkout process you will not see that order numbers in your list since there will never be an order with that increment id.

You can check the `quote` table for entries in the column `reserved_order_id`. If you find the missing numbers there, you have the answer.

There are also cases when an order number is requested by some modules even though there is already a `reserved_order_id` set in the quote. In that cases you need to debug your code.

But anyway: If you see all orders you expect and have no customer complaints, you don't need to worry about missing increment ids in the order grid.

Comment: When customer is redirected to payment system, doesn't it create a pending order with an order number?

Answer (score 0):

I found this in magento documentation (https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/before/before-workspace-magento-prereqs.html#database):

> The MySQL configuration parameter auto_increment_increment is set to 1
> by default in a local MySQL installation. You need to change this
> value to 3. The Magento Commerce database cluster includes 3 database
> implementations. The increment ensures data is unique across all
> databases for consistent data in the High Availability structure.

It explains why the order id are incremented 3 by 3.
Plus the reason of reserved_id when there some issue during the payment for example.